# Photosphere on pre 4.2 devices

Tags: android, photosphere

Are there any possibilities to view photosphere images via intent or something else on pre 4.2 android devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewing photospheres is available for all 2.2+ devices with Google Play Services 2.0
Check examples and [sdk reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/PanoramaClient.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should check [THIS](https://github.com/kennydude/photosphere) project out. While it's not as easy as simply firing off an `Intent` it is definately possible to make this work on older devices.

Heres an example of what it looks like in a browser:
http://kennydude.github.com/photosphere/test.html

Answer (score 0):

As paiNie said, we have made the Photo Sphere viewer available on all devices running 2.2 an up through Google Play Services.

You can find some example code for how to use it here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html